# Node.js - Try/Catch memory leak?

Tags: node.js, memory

I have a socket server that accepts JSON strings. I get about 10 requests per seconds so its a very busy server.

I use the following code to decode it

```
try {
  let result = JSON.parse(data);
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

I am using try/catch for obvious reasons since sometimes i get invalid json string.

Now the problem is that if the JSON is invalid, the string remains in memory.

Check the following screenshot
https://screencast.com/t/SVkcpuHbkrSK

And the memory keep going up, it reached almost 200mb in about 30 minutes. There was an issue and i received a lot of invalid json string and it broke the instance leaving the server without RAM.

If i get only valid JSON string, everything works fine.

To make sure that was the issue i kept only the try/catch code, nothing happens afterwards.

Edit.

Actually you can just use this code

```
var test = function () {
    try {
        let result = JSON.parse('invalidData');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
setInterval(function () { test(); }, 100);
```

Comment: What version of node.js are you measuring it in and on what platform?  I can't reproduce it on node v8.8.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: If you're executing this with a `console.log()` statement ever 100ms, the first thing I'd do is remove the `console.log()` statement to make sure you're testing just the try/catch, (not just measuring the console using more and more memory).

Comment: @jfriend00 i am using 9.4.0 on centos. Tried without the console.log and same issue. And after a while, the node instance exists with: FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory